# Python webdriver tests failing on Jenkins

Tags: python, selenium, jenkins

I am using selenium webdriver and python to write automated tests. The tests pass without any problems when i run them from my computer using windows batch command. I configured Jenkins server on the same computer to execute windows batch command python test.py - the test runs, but fails when it is supposed to click on a confirm button. I tried various selectors, but still the same issue. The element is visible and enabled, but the script just doesnt click the desired element (in this case button containing 'OK')
Any help?

Answer (score -1):

I often use autoit for such tasks.If keyboard enter button can click the "ok", then i recommend using autoit in your python code. If "ok" can be highlighted using {TAB}, use tab before enter in below code.

```
import autoit
autoit.send("{ENTER}")
```